# how can you add background image when using theme in styled component?

Tags: styled-components

I am coding two themes, one dark and one light, and I want to add different background to each.

I tried importing the image to the theme page but it didn't work.

Any idea on how to do it?

#### LightTheme.js:

```js
const theme = {
    id: 'light',
    primaryColor: '#f8049c',
    secondaryColor: '#fdd54f',
    bodyBackgroundColor: '#FFFFE0',
    bodyFontColor: 'black',
    navFontColor: 'black',
    wrapperColor: "papayawhip",
};
```

```
export default theme;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by simply import your asset and add it to your theme file.

1. Import your image asset.

```js
import img1 from '../assets/img1.jpg'
```

2. Add to your theme

```js
const theme = {
    id: 'light',
    primaryColor: '#f8049c',
    secondaryColor: '#fdd54f',
    bodyBackgroundColor: '#FFFFE0',
    bodyFontColor: 'black',
    navFontColor: 'black',
    wrapperColor: "papayawhip",
    backgroundImg: img1 
};
```

3. Use in some component the image.

```js
const Content = styled.div`
  background-image: ${({ theme }) => theme.backgroundImg};
`
```

Comment: this method works, thanks!